# Is there a word for 'welcome to leave'?

Tags: single-word-requests

To signify someone's presence is tolerated (or event enjoyed), you may use "welcome", as in "you are welcome".

Contrary, you can be in situations where it's ok for someone to leave, without offending the host.

Example: a meeting turns to a subject which may be boring to some parties. I don't mind them staying, but want to signal they're 'welcome to leave' with no hard feelings.

Comment: [Yes, Quora is your site.](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Is-there-a-word-for-welcome-to-leave).

Comment: Thanks, but that Quora page only suggests phrases as alternatives (besides "dismissed" which is an order to leave, not what I'm after). I'm after a single word.

Comment: I can't think of a single word so I'll comment not answer.
I'd say something:  *That's the end of the scheduled meeting; thanks everyone! However I'm going to remain on and cover subject-Z so if anyone wants to stay on you are welcome to do so.*

Answer (score 1):

you could say -

please **feel free** to leave if the current subject does not interest you.

feel free:

> If someone tells you to feel free to do something, they mean that you
> can do it if you want to.

source - [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feel-free)

Comment: I'd actually prefer if someone said "Feel free **to stay** if the current subject interests you."

Comment: It could be also be used to imply that you won't stop them from leaving, in this context that made more sense to me, thanks for your comment!

Comment: this is definitely a nice phrasing, but I'm specifically looking to capture the sentiment in a single word. Maybe borrowed from another language?